# Given a number A(=2^N), how to get the N?

Tags: c

For example,

```
Input   result
2       N: 1
4       N: 2
8       N: 3
```

Is there such function that I can directly use in `c`?

Or is there any quick simple method to get the N?

Mine:

// assume A is not very big

```
int getN(int A) {
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0;;i++) {
    if( 1 << i == A ) return i;
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to store big numbers? As char*?

Comment: Use [log2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/log2) or [ilogb](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/ilogb)

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to fit in a `long` (i.e. at most 64 bits)? Please **edit your question**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is - `log2 ( double d )`

Use like this:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define N somenumber
int main(){
    int a = 1 << N;                     // == 2 raised to the power of N
    printf("%d", (int)log2((double)a)); // output: N.   can leave out the cast, for double format result
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the input fits in a `long`, if you don't care much about performance, use `log2` to compute the [logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) in base 2 (then cast it to an int) per [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46823409/841108) answers. BTW your naive `getN` is practically fast enough (but would loop indefinitely for a 0 input, you could limit that with `for(i = 0; i<64; i++)` ), and might even be faster than a `log2`, and you could make it a `static inline`  function (in some header file).

If you are using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and if you know that the input is a power of 2 (so has exactly one bit set), you could use the faster `__builtin_ffs` [builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) (find first set bit).

If the number is very large, you want to do [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). Then use a library like [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 2):

If you like to use a custom recursive function to get N , use this function. Otherwise go for log of input.

```
int getN(int num){
    if((num/2)==1){
        return 1;
    }
    else if((num%2)!=0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return (1 + getN(num/2));
    }
}
```